# Wrapped Array of Any type to Array type in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I have a WrappedArray value of type Any. How do I convert to Array.

For Ex:

```
val flds = valArr(0)(2)
flds: Any = WrappedArray(F1,F2,F3,F4,F5)
```

I tried converting flds to String Array..

```
val flds = valArr(0)(2).toArray
```

But I got the below error

```
<console>:41: error: value toArray is not a member of Any
```

How do I convert..? I just want to loop through wrappedArray, But I didnt know how to do that.. Thats why I am trying to convert it to Array and loop through it.

Comment: WrappedArray should behave like an Array so you can loop as you generally do in an Array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how to get `WrappedArray` from `Array` and vice versa:

```
val warr: WrappedArray[Int] = WrappedArray.make(Array(1, 2, 3))
val arr: Array[Int] = warr.array
```

or

```
val warr: WrappedArray[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3) // implicit conversion
val arr: Array[Int] = warr.array
```

Comment: So how does this solve the problem when the value is an "Any".
Spark's dataframe is returning Any=WrappedArray

Comment: @CarlZmola casting?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a **WrappedArray[Any]**

```
val warr: WrappedArray[Any] = WrappedArray.make(Array(1, 2, 3))
```

I can get to an **Array[Int]** this way:

```
val arr: Array[Int] = warr.toArray.map(_.asInstanceOf[Int])
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to tell Scala that your `WrappedArray` is a `WrappedArray`, so

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
val warr = flds.asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[T]]
```

where `T` is the type of the array contents. Afterwards you will have all the methods of `WrappedArray` available, e.g. `warr.toArray`.